# Alias to folder on external hard drive disappears from sidebar when the hard drive is ejected

Tags: finder, external-disk, alias, sidebar

I've made an alias to a folder on my external hard drive and added it to Finder's sidebar. Whenever I eject the external hard drive the newly added item to the sidebar disappears and doesn't reappear when the hard drive is plugged back in. I want it to disappear when the external hard drive isn't connected and REAPPEAR when the external hard drive IS connected. How can this be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an alias on the desktop or a folder, and then either copying that or creating an alias to it in Finder's sidebar (that is, an alias to an alias).